# Closing an opened window on mobile safari with javascript?

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

In app mode, if I open a new window using javascript, the newly-opened window cannot close itself (on an on-click event) using the standard window.close() or self.close().  Does anyone know if there's an alternate method?

What I find most beguiling about this is that it goes against Apple's very own design guidelines: essentially a site has the ability to open a new window but the user cannot get out of it without closing the webapp using the Home button.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:window.self.close() is how to do that.

Comment: I have confirmed that on an iPhone 4 with iOS 6.1, this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this js code snippet.
`var win = window.open('','_self');
win.close();`